# NodeJS Lambda won't recognize index module

Tags: node.js, typescript, lambda

I'm trying to create a lambda function through IntelliJ WebStorm using node 16.
I wish to have it using Typescript and modules rather than plain Javascript with commonJS.
My problem is, when I deploy the function and try to run it, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'index'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'index'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:996:17)",
    "    at async Object.UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1031:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1194:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1200:1"
  ]
}
```

All my files sit in the root directory, including:
index.mts, node_modules, packge.json, tscofing.json, .aws-sam
My handler func is set to 'index.handler' and the code inside index.ts is as simple as it can get:

```js
import {Handler} from 'aws-lambda'

export const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {
    return {
        status: 200
    }
};
```

Package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "responsive-score-lambda",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.114",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-lambda": "^1.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

When I converted my project to vanilla JS and changed to commonJS, it ran perfectly with exports.handler = func()

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [Building Lambda functions with TypeScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-typescript.html): Because Node.js doesn't run TypeScript code natively, you must first transpile your TypeScript code into JavaScript. One simple option is to [use SAM](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-use-typescript-for-aws-lambda-in-3-steps-1996243547eb).

Comment: Using sam init has a preconfigured option for TS setup. It worked perfectly fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {//...}
```

Also, Try zipping the files inside the folder. Not the folder itself. Only zip the files inside the folder.[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Comment: I used [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission) to create lambda. 
And default for handler is:  `exports.handler`.  After changed to: `index.handler` . It worked.
So make sure handler config correct.
Thank @hassan, your answer helped me.